# Need to know how the following code works

Tags: perl

```
foreach my $x (@A) {  # read: "for each element x in array A ..."
    if ( ! ($f->($x)) ) {
        $answer = 0;
    }
}
```

I came across these lines of code. `f` appears to be a function for checking if there are any negative values in array, return false, if all values are true, only then return true. But I did not get how function `f` can do this.

Comment: Contrary to what you said, `&$f` doesn't check if there are any negative values in `@A`. It simply checks if *its argument*, `$x`, is negative.

Comment: Have a look at the rest of your code and show where `$f` is set. There must be some `$f = \&actual_function;` or `$f = sub {…};`. And _that_ is the function that gets called for each `$x`.

Comment: For all we know, `$f->()` could be `sub { -1 }`. We don't know what it does.

Comment: @simbabque, Except we were told, even though somewhat incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$f` is a code reference, not a function. That means it can be passed around like any other variable. It takes one argument (each element of `@A` in turn), and returns something that is then inverted. Without seeing the definition of `$f`, we can't explain how it works.

If you don't know where it's defined in your code, you could use [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse) to take a look. Just put this over your `foreach` loop and then run. It will output an approximation of the code that was used to define `$f`.

```
require B::Deparse;
print B::Deparse->new->coderef2text($f);
# foreach ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`$f` isn't a function, it's a *reference* to a function.  So, you're looping through each value in the array `@A`, setting `$x` to each in turn, and using that `$x` as a parameter to whatever function `$f` points at.